# Print 2 columns of a csv file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sh

In the Unix terminal, I am using:

```
    cat file.csv | cut -d ',' -f4| less
```

to print out column 4, how can I make it so that I can see both column 4 and 6

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try only `cut` with Input_file, you need not to use `cat` in it.

```
cut -d ',' -f4,6  Input_file
```

Or if ok with `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $4,$6}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you, the first one worked! But I don't really understand why

Comment: @AlexRodriguez, Glad that it helped you. It worked since we mentioned `4,6`  so it tells `cut` to print 4th and 6th field. You could use `awk` it could help you in difficult stuff/reporting/data manipulation too.

Comment: So removing the cat had nothing to do with it? it was just unnecessary?

Comment: @AlexRodriguez, yes you are right. `cut` is capable to read Input_file by itself.